# Remove tomcat autostart

Tags: tomcat, ubuntu, autostart

When I run ubuntu, the tomcat server I have installed runs automatically and I have to switch it off manually. I want tomcat not to start automatically on boot. How to disable tomcat's startup on boot?

Answer (score 40, accepted):

-> first: find out the name of the service. for example: tomcat or tomcat6

Than: try this:

> sudo update-rc.d tomcat remove

You can use the following tool:

```
sudo sysv-rc-conf
```

http://dotgiri.com/2009/08/31/alternative-for-chkconfig-in-ubuntu-sysv-rc-conf-enable-or-disable-services-at-startup/

If this doesn't work, the next will work

1.) find out your current runlevel

```
runlevel
```

2.) (re)move the startscript from the runlevel directory
/etc/rcX.d (wher X is the number of the current runlevel) Example:

```
mv /etc/rc5.d/S90tomcat /etc/rc5.d/disable.S90tomcat
```

The script starts with S and an Number (for example S90tomcat), which means: S=stratscript for tomcat, Start at position 90.

Simply delete or move that script.

3.) Finally also remove the stop-Script (Kill Script) which looks like /etc/rcX.d/Kyytomcat where yy is an number between 0-99 and X is the runlevel, you still know.

```
mv /etc/rc5.d/K01tomcat /etc/rc5.d/disable.K01tomcat
```

Look at this
http://www.unixtutorial.org/2009/01/disable-service-startup-in-ubuntu/

Comment: Note: that the default tomcat service name is "tomcat7" in ubuntu 14. If your tomcat is tomcat6 you will need to do "sudo update-rc.d tomcat6 disable" else you will get error

Answer (score 1):

I installed tomcat using [this](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-apache-tomcat-8-on-ubuntu-14-04) tutorial and following solution  worked for me.

**Edit tomcat.conf**

```
   sudo vim /etc/init/tomcat.conf
```

I changed start on runlevel value to

```
    start on runlevel []
```

**Stop autostart**

```
    sudo initctl stop tomcat
```

Answer (score 1):

When the Ubuntu OS reboots, the Apache Tomcat Server will start automatically. This program setting can be changed by entering one of the following two commands.

`sudo systemctl enable tomcat9`

OR

`sudo systemctl disable tomcat9`

[image]

source: https://linuxhint.com/install_apache_tomcat_server_ubuntu/